# Problem encounter during deployment Rails app to Firebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-hosting

my Rails app was successfully deployed in 2020 to Heroku. However, I have stopped paying for the premium plan, so I'm moving my Rails app to Firebase. Unfortunately, it's not working, and I can't even run a local server using 'rails server' anymore. Where did I go wrong?

also, how can I guide Firebase to use my own index.html.erb?

[image]
[image]

```
Started GET "/__/firebase/10.1.0/firebase-app-compat.js" for ::1 at 2023-07-21 22:26:21 +0200                           Started GET "/__/firebase/10.1.0/firebase-auth-compat.js" for ::1 at 2023-07-21 22:26:21 +0200                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory                                                       Is the server running locally and accepting                                                                             connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?                                          ):                                                                                                                      PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory                                                       Is the server running locally and accepting                                                                             connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?                                          ):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      pg (0.21.0) lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'                                                                                pg (0.21.0) lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'                                                                                       pg (0.21.0) lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
```

I used ChatGPT and Firebase tutorial.

Comment: Firebase Hosting can't run any code on the backend (your ruby code). It only hosts static content.